# Benchmarking robotic systems

Tags: performance

First of all, what does benchmarking robotic systems include?

Because, while searching the internet, I came across 2 different definitions. The first one included the state and comparison of different systems on the market. The second included defining a set of tests, measures and tasks to qualify the system's performance.

Which is the right definition? To start a successful benchmarking, what steps should be followed?

Any advice or reference should be a great help.

Comment: I work for a a company doing AI, I can give you some advice, but it will be great if you give us more context as the current question is too generic.

Comment: How is this about project management? (and those two definitions are not contradictory, however one is a little wrong: there is no need for them to be on the market.)

Comment: @Roberto Anzaldua what details you need me to add ?

Comment: As for ctrl-alt-delor I was not sure where does this question belong so I thought posting it here would be relevant

Comment: Actually @Abyr, I just noticed that ctrl-alt-delor is right. It depends on what you want to benchmark: the system against a competitor, or the system against itself.

Comment: How can you benchmark a system against itself ??

Comment: I meant, just metrics of how the current system is working.

Comment: That won't be possible as it's still in development phase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, there are 2 classic definitions of benchmarking:

- Comparing to others in the market
- Comparing to oneself over time

Then there's a 3rd. according to the [Dictionary](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/benchmark?s=t), related more to computing:

- comparing to a defined imaginary reference

Or as the dictionary says: an established point of reference against which computers or programs can be measured in tests comparing their performance, reliability, etc.

Related to robotics, [this blog](https://blog.robotiq.com/what-is-robot-benchmarking) *claims Technical industries often have well-established benchmarks, **but not robotics***.

It then goes on to inform us that *a team of [researchers at Yale announced](https://phys.org/news/2016-11-standard-robotics.html) their proposal for a suite of task-based benchmarks for robotic manipulation. The test suite contains of 77 objects and can fit in a suitcase*.

I suggest you read that [blog entry](https://blog.robotiq.com/what-is-robot-benchmarking) to become familiar with the latest trends in robotics benchmarking.

So, to answer our question: Neither definition may be correct. The task may require a newly developed Robotics benchmarking suite.